# Children property

Tags: c#

```
            public List<Channel> Children
            {
                get {  return myChannels.Where(c => c.ParentChannelId == this.Id).ToList(); }
            }
```

is this the right way to get children ? it does work, 
the question is if its the only way.

could give me an example for other methods of acheiving the same thing? (if there are any others?)

Answer (score 6):

Generally, you should return the items as abstract as possible. If you are just going to loop through the items and don't need it to be a list, you should use `IEnumerable<Channel>` as return type, even if you actually return a `List<Channel>`.

Instead of returning it as a list, you can return it as an enumerator:

```
public IEnumerable<Channel> Children {
  get { return myChannels.Where(c => c.ParentChannelId == this.Id); }
}
```

Instead of creating a list, this will return an enumerator that can produce the items. The advantages is that there is almost no work done when you call the property, and it doesn't allocate memory for a list. The drawbacks is that there is some overhead for each item that you get from the enumerator as it has to loop through items in the source until it finds one that matches the condition, and you have to hang on to the original source (`myChannels`) as long as you are using the enumerator.

One big advantage of this approach though is that it's flexible. You can just use `.ToList()` on the result, and you are back at allocating a list for the items.